# 404s on all pages except homepage

Tags: 7, uri

I have copied a Drupal installation onto my local machine and I am now running into an issue where only the homepage will load and all other links return a 404.

Clean URLS are enabled but even attempting to manually type the URL like:

```
?q=admin/module
```

fails...

I have tried the following:

- Setting AllowOverride to All
- including the mod_rewrite module
- including the usr_module
- setting the baseURL in settings.php

None have yet appeared to have any effect.

Can anybody suggest anything else to try?

Comment: check for .htaccess issues or run YOURHOST/update.php from a browser to rebuild menus etc perhaps?

Comment: I will... thanks.

In the meantime, I turned off CleanURLs in the settings.php file and I can now get access but it's not ideal.

Comment: If you are using IIS check your web.config file and follow this guide. [Drupal clearn URL guide](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/configuring-clean-urls/clean-urls-with-iis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you have the .htaccess file present in your Drupal root folder.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me once, I copied an entire site folder and clean urls didn't work. I'd copied my files by just selecting all the files in a folder, which doesn't select hidden files, so I was missing my .htaccess file in the drupal root folder.

Answer (score 0):

This problem could also be caused by editing your Apache config file and changing the default value of DocumentRoot "/var/www/html". Try keeping it at the default even if your site's files are not located in /var/www/html.